# Drug Efficacy - Probability Plot for Sputnik V

Tags: cumulative-distribution-function, dose-response

On the Wikipedia page of [Sputnik V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sputnik_V_COVID-19_vaccine) vaccine, results of Phase III study are reported, where the drug efficacy is visualized for the first and the second vaccination (attached picture).[image]

Does this plot even make sense? From my previous experience, I expected to see CDF or ROC curve.

Answer (score 0):

It may seem contra-intuitive, but it does indeed make sense. Think of the extreme points:

There's a 0% chance that the efficacy is *exactly* 73% and 92%.
There's a 100% chance that the vaccine has an efficacy between 0% and 100% after the second dose.

But it is increasingly probable that the efficacy is between those given intervals at each given probability. Example:

There's a 70% probablility that after the first dose the vaccina has an efficacy of 66%-77%.